# Why the redirect doesn't work perfectly in rails, while I am trying to add a method for that it always looking for the main method in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

EX :

```
class OrdersController  < ApplicationController
   def create
      Order.create!(
                 id:2,
                 date:Date.today
               )
      redirect_to cart_path(id: 2),method: :delete
   end
end
```

Here, I am using that delete method to call the destroy action in the carts controller but it always showing like missing routes. There is no action called show, like that it showing.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

> but it always showing like missing routes. There is no action called show, like that it showing. Why?

You can't do DELETE redirects, that's why. Only GET. This is how HTTP works.

Comment: Yes sir thanks,do you have any alternative solution.

Comment: @ARAVINDP: to a problem I don't know? Nope, I don't.

Comment: @ARAVINDP I guess you are trying to empty the cart after the order is created, you can simply find it `cart = Cart.find_by(id: 2)` and destroy it `cart.destroy if cart.present?`, and redirect the customer to any page you want.